# What is this old RPG where players have to mitigate the effects of time travel?

Tags: product-identification, time-travel

So I'm looking for a Time Traveling based RPG in which the players have to actively mitigate their actions to make sure they don't break reality and the more they do the higher chances they have of completely becoming dismissed from reality.  For example

> *A player is put into prison but finds a key they placed there themselves under the mattress.  They must then go back in time, after they escape, and place the key there so that they don't accidentally erase themselves from time.*

Any ideas on what it is called?

Comment: Can you detail “old”? Are you talking 90s, 80s, “ten years ago” kinda old, etc.?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I suspect this is probably the game [*Continuum*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuum_(role-playing_game)) from [Aetherco](http://www.aetherco.com), which centers on time travel and has players accumulating points of "frag", the in-game lingo for harmful effects of time paradox, if they don't keep their histories consistent.